# Bionic 18.04 - What packages to use for 'slv2-jack' 'slv2-jack' 'slv2-jack'

Tags: apt, 18.04, package-management

I was going to have myself a good ole time using purr-data, https://git.purrdata.net/jwilkes/purr-data, and discovered, horror of horrors that Bionic does not have some packages the lead maintainer lists as dependencies.

```
E: Package 'slv2-jack' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libslv2-dev' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'libjpeg62-turbo' has no installation candidate
```

Well.     Shucks.

Suggestions please.

Comment: Apparently already discussion on this. I'll see if it compiles without the libraries. http://disis.music.vt.edu/pipermail/l2ork-dev/2018-February/001634.html

Comment: You can try to this the dirty-way. Download .debs from previous ubuntu, unpack them with dpkg -x your.deb destdir and copy them into root fs or i.e. symlink from /opt.

Comment: awesome @Comar. good to know that is an option in a pinch

Comment: `dpkg -x` is a last resort, at first try `apt install ./some-package.deb`. I'll write complete answer.

Comment: compilation completed successfully without those libraries. Maybe I'll put in a merge request to update the docs on Gitlab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The SLV2 JACK packages are not available in *bionic* (18.04 LTS) repository, but you can install them from *xenial* (16.04 LTS) repository manually:

```
cd ~/Downloads

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/slv2/libslv2-9_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libslv2-9_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/slv2/slv2-jack_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./slv2-jack_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb

wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/universe/s/slv2/libslv2-dev_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libslv2-dev_0.6.6+dfsg1-3build1_amd64.deb
```

The `libjpeg62-turbo` is available from Debian Stretch repository:

```
cd ~/Downloads
wget http://ftp.debian.org/debian/pool/main/libj/libjpeg-turbo/libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
sudo apt-get install ./libjpeg62-turbo_1.5.1-2_amd64.deb
```

Note: usually this method is not recommended, but in this particular case it is allowed.